# Throw exception if magical converter (?) finds no resource for @PathVariable

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I just discovered I can have my controller's request parameters converted into resources without having to touch a repo or register a custom converter. I'll be honest, I'm not sure how this works (default converters? spring data rest?), but it's pretty awesome.

The only thing I'd like to have yet, is a **NullPointerException or ResourceNotFoundException thrown if a resource can't be found for the @PathVariable.** Does anyone know if this is possible?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<School> getSchool(@PathVariable("schoolId") School school) {

    // do I have to throw this manually?
    if (school == null) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }
```

Using Spring Boot 1.2.1.RELEASE, spring-data-rest, spring-data-jpa.